# Chernoff bound on probability of binomial random variables is the maximum of its tail

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, bounds

I have this problem that I found on the paper I'm reading. In that paper, it is given that random variable $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where each $X_i$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p=1/6$ and they are i.i.d. The bound on its tail probabilities are given using the Chernoff bound with
$\mathbb{P}[X \leq \lambda_0 np]  \leq e^{-\frac{(1-\lambda_0)^2}{2} np}, (0<\lambda_0<1)$ for the lower tail and $\mathbb{P}[X \geq \lambda_1 np ] \leq e^{-\frac{(\lambda_1-1)^2}{3}np}, (1<\lambda_1 \leq 2)$ for the upper tail. However, I cannot understand how the paper come to conclusion that the probability that $X$ be less than $\lambda_0 np$ or more than $\lambda_1 np $ is less or equal to $max ( e^{-\frac{(1-\lambda_0)^2}{2} np},e^{-\frac{(\lambda_1-1)^2}{3}np} )$. To my understanding, the probability of those events are $\mathbb{P}[X \leq \lambda_0 np] + \mathbb{P}[X \geq \lambda_1 np ]$. I don't see how the maximum of one of the bound is enough to bound the sum of these probabilities.

Comment: i agree with you that the claimed inequality is wrong a priori. what is the paper in question ?

Comment: The paper title is [Unconditional Byzantine Agreement and
Multi-Party Computation Secure Against
Dishonest Minorities from Scratch](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=8d7b393a9b83ce3e838046afaaae57217449acb3) . in the Lemma 4. Although my question is slightly different, I believe it has the same interpretation to prove the lemma, with each outcomes following the binomial distribution with $p=1/6$, but I just can't see how this lemma is proven.